# How to identify four sided polygon (not rectangle) collision detection?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, physics, collision-detection

I am developing 2D game for iPhone, for that I need to handle collision detection.

My need is: I have two polygons, each is a four-sided polygon (not a rectangle), I need to check whether they are collided or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See a good tutorial at CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/PolygonCollision.aspx